# How to use Vector Images as LaunchScreen in iOS 9 app?

Tags: ios, image, vector

I am trying to use a pdf image file as Vector Image for LaunchScreen in iOS 9 app but it doesn't shows up. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you explain? Do you want to show a pdf image within the launch screen, or the launch screen will be a single pdf image?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to use pdf as a vector image in the launchscreen. I used an Image View. It works in simulator but not on phone.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [iOS Human Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

> For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended. You should
> avoid using interlaced PNGs.

Meaning, they don't guarantee support for other formats. You can try to use a launchscreen.xib with a fullscreen uiimageview for greater control over your launch screen interface.